# Varnish, setup to use 80% of the my disk space

Tags: varnish

I just want to validate my setup of using Varnish. I have dedicated machine with 500 GB, disk space and my objects that I am going to cache are going to be huge (~ 500 MB) in size each.

I am going with the default configuration like this.

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -u varnish -g varnish \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s file,/var/lib/varnish/varnish_storage.bin,80%"
```

Is it alright to use 80% of the disk space for varnish.
Will there be any performance impact on using 80% of 500 GB disk size on serving from the cache.

Also, I see that varnish docs mention about sizes in Tebibytes, so I don't think size is a concern here. Can some validate this?

Answer (score 1):

The performance will be limited by your hard drive's performance. Depending on the access pattern of the content cached, performance could be poor since varnish may need to randomly seek thousands of small files.

Consider using memory rather than disk if possible, you will have less capacity but the performance for the most frequently access content maybe better than slower performance for more content.